# PercentPipe adding decimal numbers randomly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a number, 0.5 I want to display this number as percentage in my Angular app. So I use PercentPipe. It display 50%, so far so good. I try to display 120 using same pipe.

```
120 | percent
```

What gets displayed on page is 12,000%. Why did it convert to decimal and add 3 zeros? I want it to display 120%

Comment: If 0.5 is 50%, why *wouldn't* 120 be 12,000%?

Comment: If 0.5 is 50% and 1 is 100% then 120 should be 12000% but not in any way 12,000%?

Comment: What?! They are the same number, the comma is just a thousands separator.

Comment: Why not just 120%? or if you have a variable {{myVariable}}%

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe) shows an example:

```
0.26 | percent
// outputs 26%
```

Therefore 1 would be 100%. In turn, 120 would be 12,000%. You mentioned yourself that 0.5 turns into 50%, so why would you expect any different with a larger number? To solve this specific issue, you can simply divide your initial number by 100.

Answer (score -1):

when you give the pipe a value if you give it 0 equal to 0% and 1.0 equal to 100%
so when you give the pipe 120 that equal to 12000%